# Database Design for Facebook Message like, application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database-design

Designing a facebook message like application for an internal application.

Is this how you would design it? any way to improve on this design? thanks :)

```
MESSAGE
Id
Subject
Content
ReadDate -- datetime
DeletedDate -- datetime
CreatedBy -- userid
CreatedOn -- datetime

MESSAGE_COMMENT
Id
MessageId
Content
CreatedBy -- userid
CreatedOn -- datetime

MESSAGE_RECIPIENT
Id
MessageId
Recipient -- UserId 
ReadDate -- datetime
DeletedDate -- datetime
```

EDIT: there might be something missing with the design or it may be incorrect, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few minor suggestions from an over-all design perspective:

1. Since you are using Pascal Case for your field names, you should also use it for the Table names to be consistent.  So MESSAGE_COMMENT should be MessageComment
2. Do not reuse the field name "Id" since it means something different in each table.  So "Id" in Message should be "MessageId", "Id" in MessageComment should be MessageCommentId, and so on
3. If the field is a Foreign Key, it should contain the name of the field it points to.  So, "CreatedBy" should be "CreatedByUserId" and "Recipient" should be "RecipientUserId".  Remember, the more explicit you are in naming your fields the less additional comments and documentation you will need and hence it will be less confusing for anyone else to understand what is intended.

Now, as far as the question of "is this an appropriate design to do X" is concerned, you will need to give more details on how you envision this system working.  It appears that the Message is the parent whereas any replies to it are considered MessageComments.  So far that looks ok.

I am not sure why you need "ReadDate" in the main Message table as that also exists at a more accurate level in MessageRecipient.  Unless of course you want to trap the FIRST time it is read but you can still get that from the MessageRecipient table by looking at all Recipients of a particular Message.

Lastly, you should consider not even having "MessageRecipientId" and using "MessageId" and "RecipientUserId" as the composite Primary Key.  This will ensure that you can only have a RecipientUserId on a Message one time without needing to create an additional Unique Index on those two fields.

Comment: Message table is the message sent by you to the other person.

Message_Recipient is the message sent from the other person to you.

So you would want to know if you read the message you sent, (Message: ReadDate, and you would want to know if you read the message you received Message_Recipent: ReadDate) hence the reason why there is two ReadDate.

Comment: @001: I am confused. Did you mean MessageComment instead of MessageRecipient as that is where the "Content" field is? Also, it now seems that you want a Message to only go to a single user yet the wording of your question "facebook like" and your example model indicate that there can be multiple recipients of a Message (or else  MessageRecipient and MessageComment can be combined). If you only want a single Recipient then please reword the question to not include "facebook like" and please include a description of how this system should work and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is pretty enogh, for sending/receiving messages.
More depends on what you would like to do...